# Why does SceneKit use same shadow map on multiple spotlights when using Metal

Tags: scenekit, lighting, metal

I set up a scene in the scene editor with three spotlights. The first one is pointing on object which casts a shadow. The other spotlights render the same shadow. Is there some limit in Metal or some setting I'm missing? This does not happen when using OpenGL.

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Do you have a sample project?

Comment: Did some more testing and this seems to be caused by the fact that I did "Duplicate node" on the lights in Scene editor. The weird thing is I did this test since my real project had the issue and there I created the lights/nodes in code. Ill do some digging and see if I can post some code where the issue is present also...

Comment: by the way, which version of iOS is that? Have you tried with iOS 10?

Comment: This is a problem with any duplication of nodes (not only lights) in the Scene Editor. The duplication is more like "instancing" or "referencing" in 3ds Max thinking, since each duplicate seems to reference all others. Make a change in one, it impacts all of them. The only things unique seem to be transformations.